# Programa em bash não exibe saida de dados

Tags: linux, bash, shell, shell-script

Boa tarde,

Programo em C e é a primeira vez que estou programando em Bash (shell-script).

Fiz algumas funções em bash, aprendi a chamar e criei um menu interativo com o usuário, meu programa faz "basicamente" a leitura de uma wordlist e busca arquivos/pastas dentro de um determinado local.

Oque acontece "ou melhor que não acontece" é, não existe mensagem de erro do programa, e nem executa o código de identificação

O menu abre, executa, no entanto ao selecionar as opções ele simplesmente retorna o menu.
O programa é bem simples.
Alguem poderia me indicar os possíveis problemas?
PS: Tirando todo o menu interativo, tirando as funções e deixando rodar só oque tem dentro da função o programa roda.

muito obrigado aos que puderem me ajudar,
att.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    banner(){
    clear
    echo "------------------------------------------" 
    echo "|     RECON DE DIRETORIOS E ARQUIVOS     |"
    echo "------------------------------------------"
    echo "|  Uso: $0 <local>     |"
    echo "------------------------------------------"
    }

    menu(){
    clear
    echo ""
    echo "------------------------------------------"
    echo "|     RECON DE DIRETORIOS E ARQUIVOS     |"
    echo "------------------------------------------"
    echo "|  [1] - Consultar Diretorios            |"
    echo "|  [2] - Consultar Arquivos              |"
    echo "|  [3] - Consultar Arquivos/Diretorios   |"
    echo "|  [4] - Sair                            |"
    echo "------------------------------------------"
    echo -n "| Escolha uma opcao: "
    read OPT

    case $OPT in
    1) buscadir ;;
    2) buscaarq ;;
    3) buscadir;buscaarq ;;
    4) exit ;;
    *) echo "Opcao Invalida" ; echo ; menu ;
    esac
    }

    buscadir(){
    for palavra in $(cat lista2.txt)
    do
    resp=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $1/$palavra/)
    if [ $resp == "200" ]
    then
    echo "Diretorio encontrado --> $palavra"
    fi
    done
    }

    buscaarq(){
    for palavra in $(cat lista2.txt)
    do
    resp=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" $1/$palavra)
    if [ $resp == "200" ]
    then
    echo "Arquivo encontrado --> $palavra"
    fi
    done
    }

    if [ "$1" == "" ]
    then
    banner
    else
    menu
    fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Fala MHenrique12, tudo bem?

Testei de uma forma que deu certo aqui, porém fiquei com algumas dúvidas...

**Pergunta 01**: Como seria o conteúdo do arquivo lista2.txt ?

**Pergunta 02**: Voce poderia me explicar essa linha do curl, não manjo muito ;-p

Alteracões que fiz para funcionar usando como base o diretório */etc*

**OBS**: O arquivo lista2.txt estava com o seguinte conteúdo:

```
cat lista2.txt 
vim 
passwd
ssh
profile
```

Sendo que *vim* e *ssh* são diretórios e *passwd* e *shadow* arquivos

**Exemplo 01**:

```
MHenrique12_recon.sh /etc

------------------------------------------
|     RECON DE DIRETORIOS E ARQUIVOS     |
------------------------------------------
|  [1] - Consultar Diretorios            |
|  [2] - Consultar Arquivos              |
|  [3] - Consultar Arquivos/Diretorios   |
|  [4] - Sair                            |
------------------------------------------
| Escolha uma opcao: 1

Diretorio encontrado --> vim
Diretorio encontrado --> ssh
```

**Exemplo 02**:

```
MHenrique12_recon.sh /etc
------------------------------------------
|     RECON DE DIRETORIOS E ARQUIVOS     |
------------------------------------------
|  [1] - Consultar Diretorios            |
|  [2] - Consultar Arquivos              |
|  [3] - Consultar Arquivos/Diretorios   |
|  [4] - Sair                            |
------------------------------------------
| Escolha uma opcao: 2

Arquivo encontrado --> passwd
Arquivo encontrado --> shadow
```

As alteracões feitas foram as seguintes:

Funcao buscadir:

```
buscadir(){
    echo

    # Verifica se o arquivo existe, caso nao exista o programa encerra.
    [ ! -f "lista2.txt" ] && echo "Arquivo lista2.txt nao existe." && return 1


    for palavra in $(cat lista2.txt)
    do
        # 01 - Lista os arquivos no diretorio que foi passado por argumento
        # 02 - O primeiro grep seleciona somente os diretorios
        # 03 - O segundo pega a palavra atual do laco

        ls -la $DIR | grep ^d | grep -E ${palavra}$ > /dev/null

        # Se tudo ocorrer bem, mostre a mensagem...
        if [ $? == 0 ]
        then
            echo "Diretorio encontrado --> $palavra"
        fi
    done
    }
```

Funcao buscaarq:

```
 buscaarq(){
    echo

    # Verifica se o arquivo existe, caso nao exista o programa encerra.
    [ ! -f "lista2.txt" ] && echo "Arquivo lista2.txt nao existe." && return 1
    for palavra in $(cat lista2.txt)
    do
        # 01 - Lista os arquivos no diretorio que foi passado por argumento
        # 02 - O primeiro grep seleciona o que nao for diretorio
        # 03 - O segundo pega a palavra atual do laco

        ls -la $DIR | grep ^[^d] | grep -E ${palavra}$ > /dev/null 

        # Se tudo ocorrer bem, mostre a mensagem...
        if [ $? == 0 ]
        then
            echo "Arquivo encontrado --> $palavra"
        fi
    done
    }
```

Inicio do programa onde sao checados os argumentos

```
# Guarda o valor passado por argumento
DIR=$1

if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
banner
else
menu
fi
```

Espero ter ajudado, estarei a disposição caso precisar ;-)